# Rumour About cyanogen mod

Tags: cyanogenmod

Some of my friends have been saying that Cyanogen os is inferior to Oxygen os as three former is not 'upgradable' any more but the latter is.I don't know how much is true and what is true. Will anyone help me get things clarified?

Comment: It appears that your friends do not understand what they say, perhaps are not updated with latest info, or maybe you gave us partial info. Whatever the case maybe, see the official info: [Marshmallow upgrade schedule for OnePlus devices](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/marshmallow-upgrade-schedule-for-oneplus-devices.406778/).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Both Cyanogen OS and Oxygen OS are skins layered on top of Android. For years, manufacturers of smartphones have put their own software on their phones in order to set their phone apart. Every skin has its pros and cons: [OxygenOS](https://oneplus.net/bg/2/oxygenos)  bundles various apps like Swiftkey and MaxxAudio, [Cyanogen OS](https://cyngn.com/cyanogen-os) bundles different sofware, like AudioFX and Privacy Guard.

I recommend you compare the two roms carefully, but there is no objective winner in my eyes.

Comment: I wanted to know more specifically about the upgrades issue.

Comment: Asserting you are talking about the OnePlus One, something happened between OnePlus and Cyanogen, causing OnePlus to develop OxygenOS. I have no clue which skins are still supported by OnePlus since I do not own one, but **if** OnePlus or Cyanogen Inc. dropped support of one of them, you are wiser to switch to the other one. At this point, I'd recommend doing some research yourself to see which rom is better supported: I'd look at public statements made by the author, release frequency and release date of initial version.